# How to represent bounds of variables in scipy.optimization where bound is function of another variable

Tags: python, scipy

I want to solve an lp optimization problem where the upper bounds of a few variables are not an integer, instead of a function of another variable. As an example, `i`, `j` and `k` are three variables and bounds are `0<=i<=100`, `0<=j<=i-1` and `0<=k<=j-1`. How can we represent such noninteger bounds in scipy lp solver?

Comment: Never mind. Got it.

Comment: If you think this is a problem someone else might run into and you have a solution for it, it would be nice to post the solution as an answer to your own question. After all, you were asking the community for help, so it would be nice to offer something to the community. If, on the other hand, this question is not something someone else might run into, then the question was off topic from the beginning. It should not have been asked and at this point it would be best to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently none of scipy's methods allows for applying dynamic bounds. You can make a non standard extension to `scipy.optimize.minimize` or `fsolve` or implement your own optimiser with dynamic bounds.

Now on whether it is a good idea to do so: **NO!**

That is because for a well formulated optimisation problem you want the design variables and their bounds to be orthogonally independent. If the bounds are changing based on other design variables then the problem is not orthogonally independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in the below way.

for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,int(i)):
        for k in range(0,int(j)):
            print(k)